# How to get response from the API (which is not in local) using webhook

Tags: dialogflow-es

An android app has been developed by my development team. For which a chatbot is to be developed. So I chose DialogFlow platform to create the chatbot. Here, the API's for the app screens has been created by the development team. For the chatbot in DialogFlow, after creating all the necessary intents, is it just enough to enter the API url in the webhook url section or do I need to apply any logic in inline editor. [Here, the API's are created using python and it is connected with MySql DB]

As a beginner to DialogFlow, I couldn't move forward. Can anyone please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you made your intents for your chatbot you will still need to write code which chooses what to do for each intent. Dialogflow's [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-overview) can explain you more about the details of what you need to do.

Below is an image of an overview of all components from the documentation. To connect your chatbot to your MySQL API you will have to write a webhook service. This service can be an API which you host somewhere or code that you write in Dialogflows inline editor. Here you can program what API's to call on each intent and how to output it to the user. More info about that can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-configure).

[image]